# No plugin found for prefix 'maven-rar-plugin'

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

```
    [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'maven-rar-plugin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.co
dehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (D:\sunguo\.m2\repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

I can download dependency jars, so my proxy setting should be OK, when i run maven-rar-plugin:rar the above error occurs. Same error when i add maven-antrun-plugin
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `rar:rar` instead of `maven-rar-plugin:rar` .

Please refer to [Maven RAR Plugin's usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Yes exactly, shame that i spend more than one hour debugging this

Comment: Thank you. By the way if maven can tell me "invalid goal" rather than the "no plugin found for...", that would be better

Comment: in fact the key term is "No plugin found for *prefix* 'maven-rar-plugin' "  :)  It is not even invalid goal bcos invalid goal means u have a correct plugin, but there is no such goal to execute. However in your case it can't even find the plugin.  I remember that there are some special rule to map the plugin to a short prefix (e.g. the first "rar" in rar:rar), you may have a search on this.  It is something like putting it under a specific group ID or so...

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for the plugin, and found a [new one at Apache](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/). There the goal to call it is [`rar:rar`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-rar-plugin/rar-mojo.html). Perhaps you try to use the [old version (Maven 1)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/maven/maven-rar-plugin)?